# How to draw border for selected tab like below image?

Tags: html, css, web, css-transitions

[image]

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2t4S.png]

My drawing is not good. But I want this like rectangle cards like tabs when I click on tab it should show as selected and this border design for selected tab. I am not able to draw this border like inverse border radius and below line with same border connected.
I can add this cards with tabs and selected functionality. but this border I am not able to draw. How to draw border like this for this selected tab?

border with curve like this: [image]

Comment: The border will only encircle the element you are applying the border to. Assuming your menu choices are each their own elements and the under part content is another element, you need to stop thinking about this as a single border line and think about it more as several border lines seamlessly aligned up `:-)`

Comment: Please see [ask]. You haven't provided enough information.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use bootstrap navs you can get it here:**

**Bootstrap Version 4**
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#nav-home

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bootstrap Navs</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home"
                aria-selected="true">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile"
                aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact"
                aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">Pringlewerreter, herg, tregrettyi sparm<br>Et et consectetur
            ipsum labore excepteur est proident excepteur ad velit occaecat qui minim occaecat veniam. Fugiat veniam
            incididunt anim aliqua enim pariatur veniam sunt est aute sit dolor anim. Velit non irure adipisicing aliqua
            ullamco irure incididunt irure non esse consectetur nostrud minim non minim occaecat. Amet duis do nisi duis
            veniam non est eiusmod tempor incididunt tempor dolor ipsum in qui sit. Exercitation mollit sit culpa nisi
            culpa non adipisicing reprehenderit do dolore. Duis reprehenderit occaecat anim ullamco ad duis occaecat ex.

        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab"> Horses sausages and goats<BR>Et et consectetur ipsum
            labore excepteur est proident excepteur ad velit occaecat qui minim occaecat veniam. Fugiat veniam
            incididunt anim aliqua enim pariatur veniam sunt est aute sit dolor anim. Velit non irure adipisicing aliqua
            ullamco irure incididunt irure non esse consectetur nostrud minim non minim occaecat. Amet duis do nisi duis
            veniam non est eiusmod tempor incididunt tempor dolor ipsum in qui sit. Exercitation mollit sit culpa nisi
            culpa non adipisicing reprehenderit do dolore. Duis reprehenderit occaecat anim ullamco ad duis occaecat ex.

        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">Rhubarb Rumbla Treltroppis<BR>Et et consectetur ipsum
            labore excepteur est proident excepteur ad velit occaecat qui minim occaecat veniam. Fugiat veniam
            incididunt anim aliqua enim pariatur veniam sunt est aute sit dolor anim. Velit non irure adipisicing aliqua
            ullamco irure incididunt irure non esse consectetur nostrud minim non minim occaecat. Amet duis do nisi duis
            veniam non est eiusmod tempor incididunt tempor dolor ipsum in qui sit. Exercitation mollit sit culpa nisi
            culpa non adipisicing reprehenderit do dolore. Duis reprehenderit occaecat anim ullamco ad duis occaecat ex.

        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Bootstrap Version 5**
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#nav-home

```html
!
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bootstrap Navs</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <button class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#home" type="button"
                role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <button class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#profile" type="button"
                role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</button>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <button class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#contact" type="button"
                role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">Pringlewerreter,
            herg, tregrettyi sparm<br>Et et consectetur
            ipsum labore excepteur est proident excepteur ad velit occaecat qui minim occaecat veniam. Fugiat veniam
            incididunt anim aliqua enim pariatur veniam sunt est aute sit dolor anim. Velit non irure adipisicing aliqua
            ullamco irure incididunt irure non esse consectetur nostrud minim non minim occaecat. Amet duis do nisi duis
            veniam non est eiusmod tempor incididunt tempor dolor ipsum in qui sit. Exercitation mollit sit culpa nisi
            culpa non adipisicing reprehenderit do dolore. Duis reprehenderit occaecat anim ullamco ad duis occaecat ex.
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">Pringlewerreter, herg,
            tregrettyi sparm<br>Et et consectetur
            ipsum labore excepteur est proident excepteur ad velit occaecat qui minim occaecat veniam. Fugiat veniam
            incididunt anim aliqua enim pariatur veniam sunt est aute sit dolor anim. Velit non irure adipisicing aliqua
            ullamco irure incididunt irure non esse consectetur nostrud minim non minim occaecat. Amet duis do nisi duis
            veniam non est eiusmod tempor incididunt tempor dolor ipsum in qui sit. Exercitation mollit sit culpa nisi
            culpa non adipisicing reprehenderit do dolore. Duis reprehenderit occaecat anim ullamco ad duis occaecat ex.
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">Pringlewerreter, herg,
            tregrettyi sparm<br>Et et consectetur
            ipsum labore excepteur est proident excepteur ad velit occaecat qui minim occaecat veniam. Fugiat veniam
            incididunt anim aliqua enim pariatur veniam sunt est aute sit dolor anim. Velit non irure adipisicing aliqua
            ullamco irure incididunt irure non esse consectetur nostrud minim non minim occaecat. Amet duis do nisi duis
            veniam non est eiusmod tempor incididunt tempor dolor ipsum in qui sit. Exercitation mollit sit culpa nisi
            culpa non adipisicing reprehenderit do dolore. Duis reprehenderit occaecat anim ullamco ad duis occaecat ex.
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**If you want to use the design without using Bootstrap:**

```css
.navbar-right {
    float:left;
    margin-right: -15px;
}
.nav-tabs {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.nav {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.nav-tabs>li {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}
.nav>li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
.nav-tabs>li>a {
    margin-right: 2px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
.nav>li>a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-tabs>li.active>a {
    color: #555;
    cursor: default;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs navbar-right">
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Also current version of Bootstrap is 5.1 can you tweak this to use BS5?

Comment: Suggesting an entire library for a CSS border question doesn't seem reasonable to me. The question didn't ask for tab _functionality_.

Comment: @Mohamed Raafat can we add curve to bottom right corner?